# Variable declared in __init__ seems to be shared between class instances?

Tags: python, class, shared, init

I wrote this piece of code and I can't figure out what I exactly did wrong. I create two instances of the 'Route' class, and somehow they share the value for the 'coords' list.

```
import random

class Route():
    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = []  
        self.distance = 0
    def Generate(self, cities):
        random.shuffle(cities)
        self.coords = cities

class Citymap():
    def __init__(self, nr):
        self.Nr_of_cities = nr
        self.cities = []
    def Generate_map(self):
        for i in range(0, self.Nr_of_cities):
            self.cities.append((random.randint(0, 750), random.randint(0, 750)))


city = Citymap(6)
city.Generate_map()

a = Route()
a.Generate(city.cities)

b = Route()
b.Generate(city.cities)

print a.coords
print b.coords
```

The output of a and b:

```
[(429, 713), (336, 611), (555, 465), (397, 227), (222, 412), (491, 322)]
[(429, 713), (336, 611), (555, 465), (397, 227), (222, 412), (491, 322)]
```

a and b should be different instances but somehow they end up sharing the 'coords' variable. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clone the `city.cities` list or it will just be shared between them :

```
a = Route()
a.Generate(city.cities[:])

b = Route()
b.Generate(city.cities[:])
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it :) I thought I would have to rewrite the whole code for sure

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the constructor, it's the `Generate` function. Change it to make a copy:

```
def Generate(self, cities):
    self.coords[:] = cities      # <<< note the [:]
    random.shuffle(self.coords)
```

Otherwise it not only mutates the list that's passed to it, but also keeps a reference to the list in `self.coords`, leading to the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Thank you too! Didn't think it would be that simple :/

Answer (score 1):

It's subtle, but you're assigning the cities array and copying the address of the cities array around. so you're not passing `city.cities` to `Generate`, you're passing the actual array itself, then it gets assigned in the last line of the `Generate` function.

You can see this by doing:

```
print id(a.coords)
print id(b.coords)
```

I was able to get it to work as expected as follows:

```
import random
from copy import copy

class Route():
    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = []  
        self.distance = 0
    def Generate(self, cities):
        random.shuffle(cities)
        self.coords = cities

class Citymap():
    def __init__(self, nr):
        self.Nr_of_cities = nr
        self.cities = []
    def Generate_map(self):
        for i in range(0, self.Nr_of_cities):
            self.cities.append((random.randint(0, 750), random.randint(0, 750)))


city = Citymap(6)
city.Generate_map()

a = Route()
a.Generate(copy(city.cities))

b = Route()
b.Generate((city.cities))
print a.coords
print b.coords
print a
print b
print id(a.coords)
print id(b.coords)
```